# best way to render data in tables in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, ng-grid

I am trying to render data in table form to front-end in angular and there i've used ng-grid and ui-grid so far.

But they seems to be slowing down performance as there are lot more rows sometimes like 200+ per grid and more than 20 grids on single page.

So the browser most of the times hangs up i just needed to show data no operation is needed to be performed on data. it just needs to be rendered.

So anybody please help if you have any other idea to render this much data in grid form.

Comment: Please clarify what is actually slowing down the browser.

Comment: did you try one time data binding? {{::data}}.

Comment: So you have 20 grids, each with 200+ rows? You have to paginate that, no way you can get good performance in this scenario.

Comment: If you have to use ui-grid, not much you can tweak on that, since you just pass data to that.

Comment: thanks people for replying i really appreciate that :)
@DTing when data loads in grids that slows down the page

Comment: @Vikash since i am pretty new to angular i don't know about this can you please give reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one time binding in your grid row. {{::data.id}}. This will boost your page performance as watches are removed after first binding is done.

But remember if you change any model changes in you cannot see them in your view when you use one time binding.

One time binding was introduced in Angular 1.3. I you are using Angular 1.3 or above version.

If you are using version below 1.3 then probably you have to change you design. Rather then showing more than 20 grids, show only one at a time based on some select drop down.

You can try ng-table directive also. But if you are using 20 grids with more than 200 rows even that becomes slow.

Angular application become slow if they have watches more than 2000. In your case there are 20 * 200 = 4000 watch. Even more watch if u have more grids and row. So better change your design or use one time binding.

Comment: hi @jagadish thanks for responding i am kind of new to angular can you suggest some refrences related to one time binding ?

Comment: Hello @BaljeetBhinder,
Please go through this blog post:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Can u mark the above post as answer. So that i will be able to give answers to some other questions

Comment: If you use one-time binding in ui-grid, it will fail to render the data once you scroll beyond the virtualisation threshold.  The DOM elements get reused as you scroll - so we change the row that a particular DOM element points to, and rely on the binding to update the data.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for how to handle this in ui-grid.

There is an option in ui-grid for `flatEntityAccess`, that improves performance a bit with the bindings.

Many people put their grids in tabs, and use an ng-if around the tab so that it only renders the grid if that tab is active.

If you need all the grids in a list down the page, presumably not all the grids are visible to a user at the same time (you couldn't have 20 grids all visible, probably only one or two visible at a time.  You can potentially detect the page scroll and use an ng-if on the grid so that only those that are actually visible are being rendered.

Ultimately the problem is that if you have 10 columns and perhaps 15 rows visible in each grid, that's immediately 150 watchers per grid, if you then have 20 grids you've got 2000+ watchers on your page, and all of them have to be evaluated whenever you scroll any of the grids.  Note that the watchers per grid are correlated to the number of visible rows, number of visible columns, and then number of grids that are rendered.  Ultimately you need to change one of those elements if you want it to go faster.

Lastly, you may want to check version - rc20 or even current unstable is faster than older release candidates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PaulL ,
the flatEntityAccess is it available for ng-grid too? i really appreciate your answer of rendering as we scroll page thanks for that

Comment: No, the flatEntityAccess is a 3.0 item, and only in very recent release candidates (maybe unstable only, but maybe rc20)

Comment: I have also seen somewhere on the web a framework that takes watchers out of the angular watcher array, and then puts them back again.  If you had some way to work out which watchers went with which grid, you could perhaps "park" the watchers that weren't associated with the current scroll action.